# QT - Resize QToolbar

Tags: qt, size, qtoolbar

i have some concatenate toolbar. For every toolbar i have call:

```
toolbar->setGeometry(x,y,width,height)
```

but i have no resize.

I try to call

```
toolbar->updateGeometry();
```

but nothing.

My goal is to expand every toolbar with my size definition

Comment: What is size policy type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good chance you are using this for repositioning your toolbars on init and saving at closing.

Here is a solid way to do that:

What you really need is to use the `QMainWindow` `saveGeometry()` and `restoreGeometry()` functions and save and load the byte array through the QSettings interface.

writeSettings

```
QSettings s;

s.beginGroup("MainWindow");

this->restoreGeometry(s.value("geometry").toByteArray());
this->restoreState(s.value("windowState").toByteArray());

s.endGroup();
```

readSettings

```
QSettings s;

s.beginGroup("MainWindow");

s.setValue("geometry", saveGeometry());
s.setValue("windowState", saveState());

s.endGroup();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [QWidget::resize( int w, int h )](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#size-prop) to resize the toolbar.

```
toolbar-> resize( 200, 20 );
```

Comment: I would very much like to know how to do that **when** the toolbar is docked. Especially when working with touch screen it would be pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

The toolbar's geometry is either managed by a layout or by the main window.

You'd need to show how is the toolbar used/displayed.